# Using Pro*C, how to fetch from a cursor opened in PL stored function without setting 'sqlcheck=semantics' option?

Tags: c++, plsql, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to fetch data from a cursor variable opened in a stored function but I always get "fetch out of sequence" error message.

Here is the stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
  p_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_recordset FOR SELECT '1' FROM DUAL UNION SELECT '2' FROM DUAL;
  RETURN p_recordset;
END TEST_FUNCTION;
```

And the Pro*C code:

```
int myfunction()
{
  ...
  EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
  SQL_CURSOR sql_cursor_pl;
  VARCHAR string_field[20];
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

  EXEC SQL ALLOCATE :sql_cursor_pl;

  // It is not possible to use embedded PL/SQL block as seen in other 
  // examples because it requieres a compilation time access to database 
  // that I don't have, so as far as I know I have to use EXEC SQL CALL
  EXEC SQL CALL sch.test_function() INTO :sql_cursor_pl;

  EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;

  //for ( ; ; )
  while (sqlca.sqlcode == '\0')
  {
    EXEC SQL FETCH :sql_cursor_pl INTO :string_field;
    ...
  }

  EXEC SQL CLOSE :sql_cursor_pl;
  ...
}
```

The stored function works fine if I use it in other PL block like the one below, so I think the problem should be in Pro*C code.

```
DECLARE
  mycursor sys_refcursor;
  string_field VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
  mycursor := sch.test_function();
  LOOP
    FETCH mycursor INTO string_field;
    EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(string_field);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE mycursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the problem and one solution. When opening a cursor in a PL/SQL block the cursor index starts from 0, but Pro*C ones start from 1. The problem I think is that Pro*C does not update cursor index at all, so one solution could be making an increment manually like this as seen [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/10336374#10336374).

```
...
while (sqlca.sqlcode == '\0')
{
  sql_cursor_pl.curocn++;
  EXEC SQL FETCH :sql_cursor_pl INTO :string_field;
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: It's enough to set `sql_cursor_pl.curocn = 1` once before the fetch-loop. Nonetheless it sounds like a bug in Pro*C

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the while condition that is tested before executing the `FETCH` command.

I usually resolve these loops using `EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND` directive. Here's an example about how to do it:

```
while(1)
{
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break; // Where a no data found occurs execute a C "break" instruction.
    EXEC SQL FETCH :sql_cursor_pl INTO :string_field;
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO ???; // Restore desired behaviour.

    ...
}
```

The first directive instructs Pro*C/C++ to execute a `break` if a no data found error occurs, that means exit the while loop.
The second directive is required to restore the desired behaviour (a break is desired here inside the while, but in the rest of the code is probably not the best choice).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my code also includes that statement before the loop just like it should, and I think that returning a cursor from a select that retrieves constant values from dual must always return a valid cursor.